# Counting items with FirebaseObservable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm using Angular 2 and AngularFire with a FirebaseObservable to get a list of "likes", using the following code:

```
likes: FirebaseListObservable<number[]>;

constructor(private angularFire: AngularFire) {
    this.likes = angularFire.database.list('/likes');
}

onClicked() {
    this.likes.push({'item': 'new like'})
}
```

I'm looping over each like using

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let like of likes | async">
        {{ like.item }}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

> I would like to get the count of all items but the following is failing:

```
<span>{{ likes.length }}</span>
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the async pipe in combination with `?` if the list returned might be null or undefined in some scenarios. If the list is always defined, you can leave out `?` and just use the async pipe.

```
<span>{{(likes | async)?.length}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Why is the async pipe needed here for the length?

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of ways of working with observables. They are very powerful, but you have to think about what you want from them.

**1. Multiple subscriptions**

This will subscribe to the observable twice, which isn't a huge deal with AngularFire, but it will cause you unexpected problems if you are using HTTP for example.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of likes | async">
    {{like.item}}
</li>
{{(likes | async)?.length}} items
```

**2. Derivative Observable**

You could create your own observable just for length, but this once again creates multiple subscriptions to AngularFire.

```
this.length = likes.map(list => list.length);
```

And then us it somewhere in your template

```
{{this.length | async}}
```

**3. Dumb / Smart Component**

Create a dumb component to use your observable.

```
<view-likes [likes]="likes | async"></view-likes>
```

And then in the child component's template, the observable has already been unwrapped.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of likes">{{like.item}}</li>
{{likes.length}} items
```

**4. Local variables / non-observable**

You could assign the list to a local variable

```
angularfire.database.list(ref).subscribe(list => this.likes = list);
```

This would allow you to directly refer to it within your template (just like the dumb component in #3), but this creates extra variables, loses your ability to modify and process the stream reactively, and possibly a memory leak if you aren't unsubscribing.

Comment: Wow thanks for this! Those observables are much to handle coming from PHP. What's your favorite way of going about this?

Comment: @Notflip #3 is the cleanest and most maintainable, #4 is probably the fastest to build.

There's a new feature in 4 that will let you save an observable that has been 'de-asynced' locally, solving this problem too.